# How to add Yii2 datepicker that in a column it was possible to choose by pressing date this date in GridView

Tags: gridview, datepicker, yii2

As a matter of fact in heading there is also a question. Came across generally how to make filtration on a column, but not the choice of concrete date.

Comment: No one is going to provide the whole code for you, as there isnt any effort shown from your side to solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation. Getting Composer package:

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui
```

in view:

```
       echo \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'date',
            ]);
```

in model(validate unix timestamp ) - date is int in DB or ..

```
    ['date', 'default', 'value' => null],
    ['date', 'date', 'timestampAttribute' => 'date'],
```

or:

```
public function beforeValidate() {
     if ($this->date !== null) {
       $this->date= strtotime($this->date);
    }
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

in filter Gridview(Search):

```
  [
     'attribute' => 'date',
     'filter' => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget([
            'model'      => $searchModel,
            'attribute'  => 'date',
            'dateFormat' => 'php:Y-m-d',
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'autocomplete' => 'off',
            ]
        ]),
    ],
```

in modelSearch:

```
public $date;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['date'], 'safe'],
        ['date', 'default', 'value' => null],
    ];
}
//...
        if ($this->date !== null) {
            $date = strtotime($this->date);
            $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'date', $date, $date + 3600 * 24]);
        }
```

As Input In GridView:

```
      [
        'label' => 'date',
        'value' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
            return  \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'date',
            ]);
        },
        'format' => 'raw'
      ],
```

Comment: in view:

       echo \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'date',
            ]);

I did not understand where it should be removed, in representation of GridView. Sorry, I am a beginner